# I'm trying to port an html file from my pc to my android tablet

Tags: android, html

I have an html file on my pc I want to port to my android tablet and use Chrome to open it.  The .html file opens fine but it can't find any of the videos, pictures, etc..  I get the error (?)

File not found

Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/IE/NVTYO89E/Videos/Chocolate Sheet Cake with Milk Chocolate Frosting.mp4.

```
Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

The code I'm using is:

```
<div class="item1">
<p class="Names" >Chocolate Sheet Cake </p>
<p class="Names" >with Milk Chocolate Frosting</p>
     <a href="Chocolate Sheet Cake with Milk Chocolate Frosting.html">
     <img src="Pictures/Chocolate Sheet Cake with Milk Chocolate Frosting.jpg"style="width:200px">
</a> 
   <div id="navcontainer" >
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Videos/Chocolate Sheet Cake with Milk Chocolate Frosting.mp4" target="_blank">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="Recipes/Chocolate Sheet Cake with Milk Chocolate Frosting Recipe.pdf" target="_blank">Recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I've tried to find how to specify file paths but to no avail.
Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help.

Tried various file path methods I found on the web but none work

Comment: C:\Users\... Is on your PC. Your app on your Android device has no access to it.

Comment: `<img src="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Chocolate.jpg">

Comment: But better use relative paths.

Comment: And the videos and pictures should be on your Android device

Comment: All the file reside on my tablet.  The error message is misleading

Answer (score 0):

**Check the file name for capitalisation or other typing errors.

Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.**

The reason this happens is that whatever thing you are opening this on doesn't have access to the file it's trying to open. The video you are trying to play should either be in a folder with your html file or hosted online. However, the video is currently stored locally (on your computer).

Comment: The error message is misleading.  All the files reside on my android tablet.  Don't know why the error message says they reside on my pc.